# Search Google images filtered by date range

Tags: google-image-search

I am trying to find recent images (e.g not older than 1 year) using a specific search term.

Is it possible specify a date range when using Google Images Search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible by URL Tweaking.

> Google’s image search feature includes an option to sort images by
>   date. The default options in Google’s left-hand menu only cover
>   results from the past week, but you can get additional results by
>   tinkering with the search URL.
>
> Google Operating System notes that by clicking the ‘past week’ URL and
>   editing the section that says qdr:w, you can get other ranges. Options
>   you can include:
>
> - `qdr:h` – Past hour
> - `qdr:hn` – Past n hours (e.g. qdr:h2 for past 2 hours)
> - `qdr:d` – Past day
> - `qdr:dn` – Past n days
> - `qdr:w` – Past week
> - `qdr:wn` – Past n weeks
> - `qdr:m` – Past month
> - `qdr:mn` – Past n months
> - `qdr:y` – Past year
> - `qdr:yn` – Past n years
>
> While searching by date can be useful, it isn’t infallible. Google
>   often uses the content surrounding an image when determining the date,
>   so an older image will show up at the top of the list if it’s been
>   featured in a recent news story or blog post.

Source: [LifeHacker](http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2011/07/search-google-images-by-date-using-url-tweaking/)